# Knockout.js : ObservableArrays element Observable Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'disposeCallback'

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I am writing an easy web app using Knockout.js but I'm having a lot of trouble accomplishing something that should be easy but i can't figure out where I am wrong.
I have a ko.observableArray and i fill it with JSON data from a php REST server.
When I add or remove items from this array, the UI updates fine.
I want the UI updated when I edit an array element too.
I read that the array's element aren't observable, so I tried to make them Observable but still it doesn't work.
Here's the code. (I omissed parts I don't consider important)

```
function sectionViewModel(){

    var self = this;
    self.sections = ko.observableArray();
            self.sectionToEdit = ko.observable();

        //code to initialize self.sections
    $.getJSON("sections", function(data){
         for(var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++){
             var id = ko.observable(data[i].id);
              var nome = ko.observable(data[i].nome);
             self.sections.push({id:id, nome:nome});
          }
     });



    self.confirmEdit = function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'sections/' + self.sectionToEdit().id,
            type: 'PUT',
            data: self.sectionToEdit().nome,
        });
    }

};

var debug = new sectionViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(debug);
```

This code works  if I don't do the for inside $.getJSON but with it, I obtain the following error:
Object [object global] has no method 'disposeCallback'  from knockout.js
in the moment i trigger the confirmEdit function.
The PUT request it's not executed either and I have no idea why.
Any help is really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `nome` is an observable, you have to unwrap it in your function:

```
self.confirmEdit = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'sections/' + self.sectionToEdit().id,
        type: 'PUT',
        data: self.sectionToEdit().nome(),
    });
}
```

Otherwise, jQuery treats the observable as an object map, including calling all functions on the object.